# Относительные пути в запускаемом через cron php файле

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер, cron

Ubuntu сервер

В директории на сайте есть php файл по адресу:

```
/var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse.php
```

В этом файле, через относительные пути от его расположения, подключены пара других файлов:

```
require_once  '../../index.php';

require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');
```

И если попытаться запустить файл через консоль (cron) командой:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse.php
```

То получим ошибки на не найденные директории и файлы, которые подключены в запускаемом php файле **'../../index.php';** и **'../../vendor/autoload.php'**

**Вопрос:** возможно ли как то запустить файл через консоль и заставить прочитать пути к подключенным файлам без указания прямых адресов?

Comment: Можете использовать магическую константу __DIR__
require_once  __DIR__ . '/../../index.php';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к запуску команды в кроне переход в директорию вашего скрипта, например:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/ && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/site.ru/parser/parse.php
```

Comment: столь же просто, сколь гениально, как сам не додумался) спасибо, работает!